# StreamingResponseBody reuses OutputStream if not closed. Is this expected?

Tags: java, spring

I noticed that the following code will use the same `OutputStream` object (same hash code on debug) if a curl request is ctrl+c, then re-run.  Even with different parameters, it uses the same `OutputStream`. This causes very odd output obviously.

The original output stream starts to throw `NullPointerException` when writing to the `OutputStream` because the underlying `HttpOutputStream` no longer exists (broken pipe).  This is why I think it is odd that a subsequent request would reuse the same `OutputStream` object.

Closing the output stream in a finally block fixes the issue.  Some examples I've seen around the web don't explicitly close the output stream.  Is the reuse of the `OutputStream` expected? Does anyone have any ideas on why I'd be seeing this behavior?

```java
@RequestMapping(value= URI_ROOT, method= RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"text/event-stream"})
public StreamingResponseBody methodName(
    ... params
) {

    return new StreamingResponseBody() {
        @Override
        public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) {
            try {
                ... code ...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.info("Migration thread interrupted.",e);
            } finally {
                IoUtil.closeSilently(outputStream); // This fixes it.
            }

        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Did you find out if `OutputStream` whether `StreamingResponseBody` should be closed?

Comment: I ended up always closing it to be safe.  I didn't end up having time to dig in deeper on why the OutputStream was being reused.