# Should OutputStream be closed explicit in StreamingResponseBody?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest, spring-web

I'm streaming a big external resource using `StreamingResponseBody` in a spring `@RestController`.

Question: should the `OutputStream` of the response body be closed explicit here?

```
@GetMapping("/{filename}")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getFile(@PathVariable String filename) {
            StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {
                resolveExternally(outputStream, response, filename);

                //TODO should the stream be closed explicit here?
                //outputStream.close();
            };

            return ResponseEntity.ok(responseBody);
}
```

Comment: sth similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653533/streamingresponsebody-reuses-outputstream-if-not-closed-is-this-expected

Comment: I know, but that question is without any answer, thus useless. The question is still: should the stream be closed, or not?

Comment: No... If you don't open/manage/own the stream you don't close it. The stream is managed externally and hence you, apart from writing to it, don't close it. You don't know what the other party (which manages the stream) wants to do with it (maybe write some more data).

Comment: @M.Deinum So did I get it right: if I'd resolve the file manually eg on my local system, it would be fine closing the outputstream inside the StreamingBodyResponse. But if I resolve it externally eg through another webservice, I should not touch it? In case, would you mind adding that as a real answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: No. You aren't opening the outputstream here, so no you don't close it. You would close the `InputStream` you used for reading the file.

Comment: Oh that's right, ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be closed by the container. Check [StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/c263cbfbe486d7712b9e46b80ed151c1eda98c74/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java#L93).

`OutputStream` wraps a native `HttpServletResponse`.

```java
HttpServletResponse response = webRequest.getNativeResponse(HttpServletResponse.class);
Assert.state(response != null, "No HttpServletResponse");
ServerHttpResponse outputMessage = new ServletServerHttpResponse(response);
```

If you follow it down you will get to `CoyoteAdapter` which is calling `finishResponse()` and closing OutputBuffer.

Comment: Can you share where is the `CoyoteAdapter` and `finishResponse()`? I don't see any call to close() of the HttpServletResponse